# Spring cloud task - worker pod not getting deleted in kubernetes

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

We're using spring batch remote partitioning based on spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes, for some reason worker pods were not getting deleted after the worker execution.  Wondering what is the configuration that kicks off the cleanup through TaskLauncher.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Though the PODs stick around, they won't be running once when the business-logic/operation in the app completes. The container/POD will switch to "Complete" status when they are done with the operation. In other words, they won't be consuming any resources. That is the [current design](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes/KubernetesTaskLauncher.java#L110-L115) - no other cleanup routine will be triggered.

We are thinking of optionally also providing a flag to clean up resources, so there's no residue of previous runs.

If you're observing something other than what was described above, feel free to update the description and clarify with more details. Perhaps also include the stream/task definition, and the pod-list output.

Comment: Thanks, there was a tomcat listener running in worker pod too, and the was stopping to flip the status to complete.